# Authorize.net sandbox transactions

Tags: testing, transactions, authorize.net

I've got authorize.net account with test(sandbox) mode enabled.

During development I'm making test transactions.

I tried to log in into my account to see the log of said transactions but it says that no transactions are found.

Is there a way in authorize.net developer tools or inside merchant account(account.authorize.net) to view said test transactions?

Comment: I don't think this is exactly on-topic for StackOverflow; you should ask Authorize.net support about this. That said, does this help? http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Transactions-are-not-showing-on-test-account/td-p/10122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be testing using a [Developers Account](http://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/). It's just like using test mode in your account but you can see your test transactions and can never accidentally be charged for a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: To clarify - TEST MODE could be used with both production and sandbox accounts. Transactions are not created in this mode.

Comment: So what it means when I disable the TEST mode in a sandbox account?

Answer (score 1):

While you are using Sandbox and test account, Authoriz.net record your each transaction which you made. To see your transactions follow the step.

1) Login to your developer(Merchant) sandbox account
2) Click on Transactions search.

3) Now click unsettled Transactions in left side

It will list down all your transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can login to the developer control panel which is exactly like a live control panel except no real transactions are processed. When you signed up for the developer account you should have been given a login ID and password. Once logged in you can view your test transactions in there under the "Report" tab.